# Cocuhbase delete documents matching text

Tags: couchbase

We have the following documents in couchbase:

```
Doc1 :
{
   property1 : "someval"
   name : "DOC_OF_TYPE1"
}

Doc2 :
{
   property1 : "someval2"
   name : "DOC_OF_TYPE1"
}

Doc3 :
{
   property1 : "someval2"
   name : "DOC_OF_TYPE2"
}
```

Is there a way to view documents of "DOC_OF_TYPE1" only ? And is there a way to delete all documents of that type from couchbase?

Answer (score 1):

From Couchbase Server 4.1 onwards this is made easy through the use of the N1QL queries and DML (data manipulation language).

Firstly create a primary index on your data using N1QL, this can be done via a Couchbase SDK, [Query workbench](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/developer-guide/query-workbench-intro.html) (integrated in the upcoming Couchbase 4.5 release) or the [CBQ tool](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/cli/cbq-tool.html) located in the Couchbase bin directory (/opt/couchbase/bin on linux, inside the .app file on OSX and in the install directory on Windows).

The following query creates the primary index on a bucket named 'mybucket', this allows you to perform any kind of N1QL query on a bucket:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `mybucket`;
```

For performance and production purposes you should create a secondary index:

```
CREATE INDEX 'document_name' ON `mybucket`(name);
```

This creates an index on every document's 'name' field. You can now efficiently select documents by their name field (This works with just the primary index but that would be slower):

```
SELECT *, meta().id FROM `mybucket` WHERE name = 'DOC_OF_TYPE1';
```

Or delete them based on their name field

```
DELETE FROM `mybucket` WHERE name = 'DOC_OF_TYPE2';
```

You can find more information about N1QL in the [Couchbase Server documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/developer-guide/querying.html)